# LWC - Css styling has problem with :not(:first-child)/:not(:first-type) and ::before

Tags: css, slds, style

I'm building a Salesforce look alike path. Because the way data display and looping in the component so I cannot use Path from lightning design system.

HTML code:

```
<template>
    <div class="card_wrapper">
        <template for:each={stagePickVals} for:item="item">
            <div class="stageContainer" key={item} style="width: 188px;">
                <h1 class="column_heading">
                    <div class="pathing">
                        <lightning-formatted-text>
                            <span class="slds-truncate" style="font-size: 13px;">
                            {item}
                            </span>
                        </lightning-formatted-text>&nbsp;
                        <lightning-formatted-text></lightning-formatted-text>
                        <span role="tooltip">{item}</span>
                    </div>
                </h1>
                <c-item-list records={records} stage={item}
                    onlistitemdrag={handleListItemDrag}
                    onitemdrop={handleItemDrop}>
                </c-item-list>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div> 
</template>
```

CSS code:

```
.card_wrapper{
    padding: 0.4rem;
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-left: var(--lwc-spacingXSmall,0.5rem);
    padding-right: var(--lwc-spacingXSmall,0.5rem);
    padding-top:1vh;
    position: relative;
}

.column_heading {
    padding: 0.5rem 0.25rem;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: rgb(1, 118, 211);
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 36px;
}

.pathing::before, .pathing:not(:first-child) {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5rem;
    display: block;
    width: 1.85rem;
    height: 1.85rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: rgb(1, 118, 211);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.stageContainer{
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid #d8dde6;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
```

I'm having 2 problems:

1. I want the `::before` to adjust to the left or right, `::before` element will be disappeared.
2. I want it to skip the first element of the loop by adding `:not(:first-child)/:not(:first-type)` but it does not work

Here is the image that captures my problem
[image]